# How to support feature toggling?

Tags: android

Whats the best way to support enabling/disabling features based on a configuration file for different countries ? I dont want to use strings.xml as strings files are supposed to be used for text resources.

I can write these rules in a json or use properties file, store it in the apk and read from there, but there could be a better way to do it?

Comment: "based on a feature file" -- please explain what a "feature file" is. "I dont want to use strings.xml" -- please explain specifically what the problem is with using resources (or if the problem is somehow limited to string resources).

Comment: @CommonsWare i have updated the question. i dont want to use resources file as that wasnt the intended purpose of strings.xml

Answer (score 1):

If your real interest is by *language*, not by *country*, create an XML structure for your configuration data, and store it in language-specific variants of `res/xml/` (e.g., `res/xml-es/` for Spanish), with an overall set of defaults in `res/xml/`. When you ask Android to give you the XML, it will choose the one for the user's current locale.

You could do the same thing with other file formats (e.g., JSON), using `res/raw/` and related resource sets. The XML approach may be a bit faster at runtime, due to some XML preprocessing that is done at compile time.

If you really do care about *country*, you are completely on your own, including for determining what country is relevant (the country where the user was born? the country where the user resides? the country that the user is presently flying over? the country where the user has travelled to?).

Comment: user will be asked to select a country. Then the app locale will be set, so the resources can be picked up from language specific folders. So my options really are use xml, json or properties file for configuration.

Comment: @rfsk2010: "user will be asked to select a country. Then the app locale will be set" -- many countries have more than one language, and many languages are spoken in one or more countries.